# how to get use 'this' inside nested setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have an input with class 'textInputs' and have a paste function for those elements, I need to nest a setTimeout function inside the paste event function, but then how can I define `this` inside the timeout function? The code below does not work as `this` is not defined inside the setTimeout function. Thank you.

```
$('.textInputs').on('paste',function() { 

       var element = this;

       window.setTimeout(function() {  
       newstr = element.value.replace(/\n/g, '');  

       $(this).val(newstr);

   },100);  
});
```

Comment: UM, you are using it on the line above with `element`...

Comment: Thanks all, it seem so obvious now, but it didn't even occur to me. Very tired. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because _the answer was inside you all along._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just used the cached one itself, `this` in the setTimeout callback points to the global context not the element.

```
$('.textInputs').on('paste',function() { 

       var element = this;
          window.setTimeout(function() {  
          newstr = element.value.replace(/\n/g, '');  
          $(element).val(newstr); //<-- Here
          //or just
          //element.value = element.value.replace(/\n/g, '');
   },100);  
});
```

You can simplify this using the [.val( function(index, value) )](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex--value) syntax:

```
$('.textInputs').on('paste',function() { 
       var $element = $(this);
       window.setTimeout(function() { 
          $element.val(function(_, currVal){ 
             return currVal.replace(/\n/g, '');
          }); 
    },100);  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you mean this ?

```
$('.textInputs').on('paste',function() { 

       var element = this;

       window.setTimeout(function() {  
       newstr = element.value.replace(/\n/g, '');  

       $(element ).val(newstr);

   },100);  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You were referencing `this` instead of your element.

```
  var element = $(this);
   window.setTimeout(function() {  
       newstr = element.value.replace(/\n/g, '');  
       element.val(newstr);
   },100);
```